# Knockout.js.... what's my issue with Observables?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kJEnE/)

My major problem is playing with observable arrays. I have a list of contacts, I want the filter to filter the list when you type but according to the debugger I get nothing from the "usual" properties of:

```
self.contacts.length
```

or even

```
contact.name
```

These are observable arrays and an observable property.

So the sort doesn't work as it fails to access left.name or right.name correctly. However it works if I make the property just "normal" and not observable.
Additionally the actual filter function needs .peek()s everywhere for the debugger to return actual values and then proceeds to fail on .name.toLowerCase().

It seems like when I define an observable I lose all of the behaviour of what its supposedly wrapping. Is this normal or have I got something horribly wrong in my environment?

---

*P.S*

```
SO says: "links to jsFiddle must be accompanied by code"
```

I say SO should do a better job of handling js/html/css questions before it starts demanding these kind of things.

Comment: If you don't post any code, how do you expect people to answer questions about your code?

Comment: How could SO do a better job of handling JS questions? Seems like a good meta discussion... Probably not good to discuss on SO itself though.

Comment: I did post code but jsFiddle offers better form for these kind of questions (small complete examples). SO could attempt to offer similar functionality to handle small but complete examples or at least try to solve the problem of having multiple files. The meta discussion already occurred and the librarians won. They always win.

Comment: @Quibblesome: There is no problem with posting your complete working example on jsfiddle and then posting just a snippet of where you think the problem might be on SO. I don't think it really makes sense for SO to provide functionality to copy jsfiddle within SO itself, but as Andrew suggested, this is getting to be a meta discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Matt already said an observableArray is a function and you need to call the function to access the properties... for example:

```
<span data-bind="text: contact().name"></span>
```

If you want to access a certain array element you can use...

```
self.contact()[0].name
```

If you want the length of the array...

```
self.contact().length
```

... and because this looks ugly when used in templates i usually create an computed function...

```
self.hasContact = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.contact().length;
});
```

... and if you want to filter/search the array...

```
self.contactFilter = function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.contact(), function(item) {
        return ko.unwrap(item.name) == 'John'
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

An observable array is a function, so to access it's length you need:

```
myArray().length
```

`myArray()` will return the underlying array with all it's functions and properties. Also be sure to check [this](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html) for more info on functions available to the observable array itself.